# Character classes in the F# spec

Tags: parsing, unicode, f#

The F# spec makes the following definition in the grammar (Section A.1.4.1):

```
ident-char :
      letter-char
      digit-char
      connecting-char
      combining-char
      formatting-char
      '
      _
```

With `connecting-char` defined as

```
connecting-char : '\Pc'
```

Which I believe means that `connecting-char` is any character `c` which satisfies

```
System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) = UnicodeCategory.   ConnectorPunctuation
```

When you test this with `_` you get:

```
> System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('_');;
val it : System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory = ConnectorPunctuation
```

Which I think means that `_` is a valid `connecting-char`.  This raises the question as to why there is a special case for `_`.

In the actual compiler source code, there is no special treatment for `_`

(from https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/lex.fsl),

```
let ident_char =
    letter
  | connecting_char
  | combining_char
  | formatting_char
  | digit
  | ['\'']
```

The question is then - Why does the F# spec have the entry for `_` in ident-char?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what you mean. `\Pc` refers to the category ["Punctuation, Connector"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm), and appears right there in the code: `connecting_char = '\Pc'`.

Comment: @GregRos The question is why the extra `_` which is in `\Pc`

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Sorry. It looks like an error to me.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this would be for either historic reasons (inherited from F#'s roots in SML) or to make it clear underscore is included (as would be expected from the typical identifier rules: underscore or alphabetic followed by zero or more underscore or alpha-numeric).

(But this is speculative, for a real answer why not ask the F# team?)